# (Not a programming question) Is there a common word to indicate predict or forecast

Tags: forecast, predict

The general understanding is:

- Predict: past value - could be data the model has seen (data from train set) or past data model has not seen (data from test set) (together in-sample data)
- Forecast: future value - data which neither model or user has seen (out-of-sample data)

Related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65287/difference-between-forecast-and-prediction

Question: Is there a common word that can mean either? This will help in talking or writing or explaining to non-technical people.

Comment: You might want to post also here (https://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I disagree with your definition of "predict", the word is not specific to past value. As the top answer in the linked question says "Forecasting would be a subset of prediction", so the word predict can be used to mean forecast as well.

Comment: Agree with @Erwan: "to predict" is something very general. Forcasts - to my understanding - refer to future periods in time. This is not necessarily the case with predictions. So I guess both words have a different notion after all.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I agree with the first one, since **predict** is widely used to replace **forecast** as well. But other related verbs we often hear are:

- To estimate
- To infer / make an inference